# Bootstrap Navbar toggle on double click

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble working with the navbar toggle. For some reason my navbar toggle items require two clicks to initiate. I can supply you with any code you need, but I'm try not sure what is causing this issue.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">

    <div class="navbar-right">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="font-family:Lato;">

            <li class="dropdown user user-menu" ng-show="user">

                <a  class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
```

I've taken pieces out of the code, I'm not showing closing tags or any of the angular.

Please Help!

Comment: Please provide complete code of your navbar, maybe here http://www.bootply.com/new

Comment: Are you using http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ ? If not, you might consider doing so.

Answer (score 2):

You may have added the bootstrap.min.js file to the page twice.

Answer (score 1):

Change the positions of bootstrap.min.js file and bootstrap.min.css file. Js file should come first and the css file should come later.

Answer (score 0):

It works just fine, are you sure your bootstrap is up-to-date? See this example using your provided code: http://jsfiddle.net/wnd2xccr/1/

Html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-right">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="font-family:Lato;">
           <li class="dropdown user user-menu" ng-show="user">
               <a  class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                   <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                   <li class="divider"></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                   <li class="divider"></li>
                   <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
               </ul>
           </li>
       </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: could it be an angular thing?